# Interpolation of survey travel data for transport modelling

Tags: interpolation, modelling

I am looking for a way to interpolate survey travel data (in VKT) for transport modelling.  I have the dataset of VISTA residential transport survey at meshblock level, but I need to get VKT (Vehicle Kilometers Travel) values for the meshblocks that were not survey.

I tried to use IDW and Spline but it is showing logical results in the missing areas. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are these meshblocks polygons, lines, or raster cells? Are there multiple values per meshblock or just one value per meshblock? What do you mean by "logical results"? Do you mean illogical? I'm having difficulty interpreting the structure of your data and outputs by this description.